How can I get Kaniko to pull in image from GCR in Gitlab
Actual behavior
In gitlab, kaniko obtains the manifest of an image, but fails to obtain the image from GCR.
Expected behavior
In gitlab, kaniko obtains the image from GCR.
To Reproduce
Steps to reproduce the behavior:
In a Gitlab repository, create the files below.
Observe build failure
ci file:
build:
  stage: build
  image:
    name: gcr.io/kaniko-project/executor:v1.23.2-debug
    entrypoint: [""]
  script:
     - /kaniko/executor
      --context "${CI_PROJECT_DIR}"
      --dockerfile "${CI_PROJECT_DIR}/Dockerfile"
      --destination "${CI_REGISTRY_IMAGE}:${CI_COMMIT_TAG}"

Dockerfile
FROM gcr.io/distroless/java17-debian12:nonroot


What are the buid failures?
